# GUI Extension - TabPage not loading JS

Tags: tridion

I am adding a new Tab to the Component Edit screen.  My tab is showing fine but the JavaScript is not loading.  I would like to write out the URI of the current Component in the tab.  I have a feeling the naming of my JavaScript methods is not correct or matching with the config, but really don't know how to say 'hello' from the JavaScript side.

I used the InfoTab View from the Tridion CME (code sample below) and also the PowerTools ItemXml for inspiration - but no luck.

What is the minimum set of methods in the JS to get hello world working?

**Solution**

Added the dependencies node from Rob's suggestion.  The log then showed the js file as loading.

HelloTab.js

```
Type.registerNamespace("RC");

RC.HelloTab = function RC$HelloTab$HelloTab(element) {
    console.log('Constructor');
    Tridion.OO.enableInterface(this, "RC.HelloTab");
    this.addInterface("Tridion.Controls.DeckPage", [element]); //My extension is like this
};

RC.HelloTab.prototype.initialize = function HelloTab$initialize()
{
    console.log('init');
    $log.debug('init');
    this.callBase("Tridion.Controls.DeckPage", "initialize");
    $evt.addEventHandler($display.getItem(), "load", this.getDelegate(this.updateView));
};

RC.HelloTab.prototype.select = function HelloTab$select()
{
    console.log('select');
    this.callBase("Tridion.Controls.DeckPage", "select");
    this.updateView();
};

RC.HelloTab.prototype.updateView = function HelloTab$updateView()
{
    console.log('update');
    if (this.isSelected()) 
    {
        console.log('selected')           
    }
};

Tridion.Controls.Deck.registerPageType(RC.HelloTab, "RC.HelloTab");
```

**HelloTab.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Configuration xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration/Merge"
               xmlns:cfg="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration"
                             xmlns:ext="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions"
               xmlns:cmenu="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions/ContextMenu">

  <resources cache="true">
    <cfg:filters />
    <cfg:groups>
      <cfg:group name="RC.HelloTab" merge="always">
        <cfg:fileset>
          <cfg:file type="script">/HelloTab.js</cfg:file>
        </cfg:fileset>
        <cfg:dependencies>
          <cfg:dependency>Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME</cfg:dependency>
          <cfg:dependency>Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.commands</cfg:dependency>
        </cfg:dependencies>
      </cfg:group>
    </cfg:groups>
  </resources>
  <definitionfiles />
  <extensions>
    <ext:dataextenders/>
    <ext:editorextensions>
      <ext:editorextension target="CME">
        <ext:editurls/>
        <ext:listdefinitions/>
        <ext:taskbars/>
        <ext:commands/>
        <ext:commandextensions/>        
        <ext:contextmenus/>
        <ext:lists />
        <ext:tabpages>
          <ext:add>
            <ext:extension assignid="HelloTab" name="Hi There!" insertbefore="InfoTab">
              <ext:control>~/HelloTab.ascx</ext:control>
              <ext:pagetype>RC.HelloTab</ext:pagetype>
              <ext:dependencies>
                <cfg:dependency>RC.HelloTab</cfg:dependency>
              </ext:dependencies>
              <ext:apply>
                <ext:view name="ComponentView">
                  <ext:control id="MasterTabControl"/>
                </ext:view>
              </ext:apply>
            </ext:extension>
          </ext:add>
        </ext:tabpages>
        <ext:toolbars/>
        <ext:ribbontoolbars/>
      </ext:editorextension>
    </ext:editorextensions>
  </extensions>
  <commands/>
  <contextmenus />
  <localization />
  <settings>
    <defaultpage/><!-- /Views/Default.aspx</defaultpage> -->
    <navigatorurl/><!-- /Views/Default.aspx</navigatorurl> -->
    <editurls/>
    <listdefinitions />
    <itemicons/>
    <theme>
      <path>theme/</path>
    </theme>
    <customconfiguration />
  </settings>
</Configuration>
```

**Original:**

**HelloTab.config**

```
<resources cache="true">
    <cfg:filters />
    <cfg:groups>
      <cfg:group name="RC.HelloTab" merge="always">
        <cfg:fileset>
          <cfg:file type="style">{ThemePath}/HelloTab.css</cfg:file>
          <cfg:file type="script">/HelloTab/HelloTab.js</cfg:file>
        </cfg:fileset>
        <cfg:dependencies>
          <cfg:dependency>Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME</cfg:dependency>
          <cfg:dependency>Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.commands</cfg:dependency>
        </cfg:dependencies>
      </cfg:group>
    </cfg:groups>
  </resources>
  <definitionfiles />
  <extensions>
    <ext:dataextenders/>
    <ext:editorextensions>
      <ext:editorextension target="CME">
        <ext:editurls/>
        <ext:listdefinitions/>
        <ext:taskbars/>
        <ext:commands/>
        <ext:commandextensions/>        
        <ext:contextmenus/>
        <ext:lists />
        <ext:tabpages>
          <ext:add>
            <ext:extension assignid="HelloTab" name="Hi There!" insertbefore="InfoTab">
              <ext:control>~/HelloTab.ascx</ext:control>
              <ext:pagetype>HelloTab</ext:pagetype>
              <ext:apply>
                <ext:view name="ComponentView">
                  <ext:control id="MasterTabControl"/>
                </ext:view>
              </ext:apply>
            </ext:extension>
          </ext:add>
        </ext:tabpages>
        <ext:toolbars/>
        <ext:ribbontoolbars/>
      </ext:editorextension>
    </ext:editorextensions>
  </extensions>
  <commands/>
  <contextmenus />
  <localization />
  <settings>
    <defaultpage/><!-- /Views/Default.aspx</defaultpage> -->
    <navigatorurl/><!-- /Views/Default.aspx</navigatorurl> -->
    <editurls/>
    <listdefinitions />
    <itemicons/>
    <theme>
      <path>theme/</path>
    </theme>
    <customconfiguration />
  </settings>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
Type.registerNamespace("RC.HelloTab");

RC.HelloTab = function HelloTab(element)
{
    Tridion.OO.enableInterface(this, "RC.HelloTab");
    this.addInterface("Tridion.Controls.DeckPage", [element]);
};

RC.HelloTab.prototype.initialize = function HelloTab$initialize()
{
    $log.event("RC.HelloTab", "RC.HelloTab init");
    this.callBase("Tridion.Controls.DeckPage", "initialize");
    document.write("something else");
    var item = $display.getItem();
    if (item)
    {
        if (item.isLoaded())
        {
            this._showInfo();
        }
        else
        {
            item.load();
        }
    }
};

RC.HelloTab.prototype.select = function HelloTab$select()
{
    this.callBase("Tridion.Controls.DeckPage", "select");

    if (this.properties.itemChanged)
    {
        this._showInfo();
        this.properties.itemChanged = false;
    }
};
RC.HelloTab.prototype._showInfo = function HelloTab$_showInfo()
{
    var item = $display.getItem();
    var html = "<h1>title</h1>";
    $dom.setOuterHTML($("#title"), html);
    document.write('another uri=' + item.ID);
};

RC.HelloTab.prototype._onItemChanged = function HelloTab$_onItemChanged()
{
    if (this.isSelected())
    {
        this._showInfo();
    }
};

Tridion.Controls.Deck.registerPageType(RC.HelloTab, "HelloTab");
```

Tridion.Web.Trace:

w3wp.exe Information: 0 : (634734775171817068) CachedJssControlResources: LastModifiedTime for type HelloTab is 5/24/2012 5:22:26 PM

w3wp.exe Information: 0 : (634734770029374585) CachedJssControlResources: LastModifiedTime for type editors_hellotab_hellotab_ascx is 5/24/2012 5:22:26 PM

Comment: You should ask a separate question for the second part really or it confuses the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is you're missing the dependency elements in the ext:extension element.

```
<ext:dependencies>
    <cfg:dependency></cfg:dependency>
</ext:dependencies>
```

Add like so:

```
<ext:extension assignid="HelloTab" name="Hi There!" insertbefore="InfoTab">
          <ext:control>~/HelloTab.ascx</ext:control>
          <ext:pagetype>HelloTab</ext:pagetype>
          <ext:dependencies>
                <cfg:dependency>RC.HelloTab</cfg:dependency>
          </ext:dependencies>
          <ext:apply>
            <ext:view name="ComponentView">
              <ext:control id="MasterTabControl"/>
            </ext:view>
          </ext:apply>
</ext:extension>
```

If you're using Chrome you could put in some console.log statements (alerts if IE) into each of the methods you have implemented from the interface as a test and at the top of the file. E.g.:

```
console.log('Hello: File loaded');
```

One difference between your code and a GUI extension I've written recently is your constructor function name does not include the namespace.

I would expect it to be called:

```
RC.HelloTab = function RC$HelloTab$HelloTab(element)
{
    console.log('Constructor');
    Tridion.OO.enableInterface(this, "RC.HelloTab.HelloTab"); //Also was missing NS here
    this.addInterface("Tridion.Controls.DeckPage", [element]); //My extension is like this
};
```

Another way to check is to use Chrome developer tools on the page you expect your Javascript to appear, go to the scripts tab and use the search box within the developer tools to search for your namespace.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I second this - the missing dependency is likely the problem. Also, the name listed after "function" is only really useful for debugging. But when you are looking at the call stack it is indeed very useful to see both the namespace and class - so I do recommend that you follow the standard of namespace$class$method.

Comment: Yes, after adding the missing dependency my js file was loaded.  However, now I am still not able to get the js methods to write to the console log.

Comment: Chrome - Console.log does work , I gett he constructor log output - but then breaks on the registerPageType in the js.  If I change the registerPageType so it does not break then my console output is not hit.

Comment: Solution found, added element instead of 'HelloTab'.  Wow - this is way too difficult!  :)  this.addInterface("Tridion.Controls.DeckPage", [element]);

Comment: Ah apologies, I got this from the Tutorial on SDL Tridion world and it is working in my case.. perhaps it is different because I am implementing a Command and you are doing a DeckPage

Comment: No worries Rob!  Your solution helped me towards a final working one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the dependency on the group with resource files is missing. That's why js was not present on the page. Btw, there are two ways to make a dependency:

1. Make a dependency in the ext:extension node (as Rob proposed)
2. If you have code behind for your HelloTab.ascx, you could use ControlResources attribute for the class definition

   [ControlResources("RC.HelloTab")]
   public class HelloTab
   {}

Some additional comments:

1. The recommended way to use `registerNamespace` is to define only namespace object, but not the class itself. So in the provided code, there should be only `Type.registerNamespace("RC");`
2. `Tridion.OO.enableInterface` used to define the unique interface name for the class and set the API functions to use OO possibilities on the class. To this call actually makes possible to call `addInterface` method. Interface name could be any string, which should be unique. Usually, we use the name of the class with full namespace. So in this case original version was correct - `Tridion.OO.enableInterface(this, "RC.HelloTab");`.

Comment: Thanks for the info Boris.  I am still having challnges getting the js working.  Can you see my update above?